# Java Servlet DB username and password store location

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I'm totally beginner in servlets.
I know I can set init params in `web.xml`.
My question is :
Is it good to store **DB user** and **DB password** in `web.xml` for the ease of configuration?
OR
Shall I store them `Hard-coded` for security wise?
In other words is `web.xml` visible to end user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Is it good to store db user and pass in web.xml for the ease of configuration?*

- It is not a very good thing to store the username and password in web.xml rather you can put the username and password in a separate file in your environment. then, provide the location of that file in your web.xml. You can also restrict the access to the file only to the root user who runs your application

*shall I store them in code for security wise?*

- Storing the username and password in code is a good idea. but, it has disadvantages like you need to recompile,build and deploy if your credentials change. The other thing is by making use of decompiler, there are chances your credentials can be identified

*In other words is web.xml visible to end user?*

- No, web.xml is not visible to end users. It is a configuration file for your web application know as deployment descriptor. This file is used by the web application server during deployment.

Hope, you understand it now!

Comment: "you can put the username and password in a separate file in your environment. then, provide the location of that file in your web.xml" is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Please try this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/357739/Servlets/java/file-location-web-xml). it's worth a read. you can go for a context param / env-entry / init-param  providing the location of the file.then, get it in your code to access the file to read the credentials. I will share you if i get one.

Comment: I would rather use a server datasource myself and let the server/container manage the database connections; usually you get the added performance benefit of the connections being pooled too.

Comment: @Gimby, yes, that's a very good option for performance benefit